# rails, cannot get params from url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

I'm trying to use Google Federated Login REST API.  I can succesfully reach out to the google server and validate a user but I cannot pull parameters from the return url

> for example:
>   http://mysite.com/login/return?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Faccounts%2Fo8%2Fud...

All the variables in that return string are not accessible in the params array.  I have no idea how to get them out. `requst.url`, `request.query_parameter`, and all similar calls do not return the query string.

Comment: They should be... What do you get when you do `raise params.inspect` in your `return` action?

Comment: {"controller"=>"login", "action"=>"return"}

Comment: I dont know why they're not available. You could use the new omniauth (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth), with this strategy https://github.com/zquestz/omniauth-google-oauth2 to achieve the same thing. It would be really easy to add new authentication services later with this method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found the issue.  I was using the open-uri library to make the call to google's endpoint url so it may have been stepping outside of the normal rails response/request cycle.  I've since used Net::HTTP requests and parse the information from the response.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a very similar issue, where I'm actually building a Rails-based openid **provider** but being consumed by another Rails app. I basically adapted the code from

The whole URL was:

```
http://localhost:3000/openid?openid.assoc_handle=%7BHMAC-SHA1%7D%7B5193d33f%7D%7BdBrUwQ%3D%3D%7D&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fopenid%2Fwarren&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2Fopenid%2Fwarren&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.ns.sreg=http%3A%2F%2Fopenid.net%2Fextensions%2Fsreg%2F1.1&openid.realm=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsession%3F_method%3Dpost%26return_to%3D&openid.sreg.required=nickname%2Cemail
```

I had a similar problem where the only parameters being reported were:

```
{"action"=>"index", "controller"=>"openid"}
```

So, suspecting that some parameter (maybe a period?) was causing it to hiccup, I went through and deleted them one by one until I found that deleting the following parameter enables the entire thing to go through correctly:

```
openid.mode=checkid_setup
```

That left all the remaining parameters correctly being parsed:

```
{"openid.assoc_handle"=>"{HMAC-SHA1}{5193d33f}{dBrUwQ==}", 
"openid.claimed_id"=>"http://localhost:3000/openid/warren", 
"openid.identity"=>"http://localhost:3000/openid/warren", 
"openid.ns"=>"http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0", 
"openid.ns.sreg"=>"http://openid.net/extensions/sreg/1.1", 
"openid.realm"=>"http://localhost", 
"openid.return_to"=>"http://localhost/session?_method=post&return_to=", 
"openid.sreg.required"=>"nickname,email", 
"action"=>"index", 
"controller"=>"openid"}
```

I'm now trying to find why openid.mode causes this issue. It fails even if I change it to openid.mode=5, so it's the key, not the value, causing the problem.

Suspecting the ".mode" part of the string for the trouble (maybe ".mode" is a filetype or something being parsed by the routing?) I am looking towards this post on allowing periods, but it only applies to the *value*, not the key: [rails routing and params with a '.' in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276125/rails-routing-and-params-with-a-in-them)

Will report back if I find more.

**Update:** I tried, in another Rails app, adding ?openid.mode=0 to the end of a URL -- ".mode" does not result in a parameter being read, but ".modes=" does and so does ".mod=". This confirms that ".mode" is causing a params parsing error.

**Update 2:** yikes... actually "?a.mode=0" does work. So far, only the complete string "openid.mode" does not work, and this is across various Rails apps. "?openid.mode" with nothing else results in: Parameters: {"openid.mode"=>nil}, but "?openid.mode=" with nothing after the "=" fails to pass any parameters besides action & controller. Very odd.

**Update 3:** OK, figured it out, I believe -- the params were getting sanitized i.e. deleted by the rack-openid gem, in that gem's path: /lib/openid.rb:168, "sanitize_query_string". This seems to be incompatible with the example I was working with: https://github.com/openid/ruby-openid/tree/master/examples/rails_openid. Going to override that method.

**Final update:** I replaced this line:

```
oidreq = server.decode_request(params)
```

with this line, since we could no longer use the now-empty params hash:

```
oidreq = server.decode_request(Rack::Utils.parse_query(request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']))
```