# Rails float as ID in URI seems to lose decimal when converting from string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it wrong/impossible to pass a float as an id in RAILS 2.x

http://mysite.com/clientversioncheck/1.1

controller:

```
def clientversioncheck
  current_version = 1.1
  client_version = params[:id].to_f
  if client_version && current_version > client_version
    render :text => "update url"
  else
    render :text => "no update " + current_version.to_s + "server vs. " + client_version.to_s, :status => 404
  end
end
```

If I'm comparing a whole number it's always fine but if I pass a float as a string the conversion always seems to drop the decimal portion.

So if current_version = 1.0 and I pass 1.0 in the url everything is fine
if current_version = 1.1 and I pass 1.1 in the url client_version evals as 1.0.

I thought . does not need to be escaped in URIs

If I boil things down to simply:

```
def clientversioncheck
  render :text => params[:id]
end
```

I get the truncation still

For instance: clientversioncheck/2.33 will output 2

I've tried the following routes:

```
  map.resources :api, :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\.]+?/, :format => /json|xml|plist|html/

  map.resources :api, :requirements => { :resource => /.*/ }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [rails routing and params with a '.' in them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276125/rails-routing-and-params-with-a-in-them)

Comment: @mu is too short - Thanks for the link that seemed like a good probable source of this issue. Unfortunately, it didn't correct things when I tried adjusting the route for this controller.

Comment: What does your route look like? Is `params[:id]` coming out right? Are you having one of the usual floating point problems? Version numbers really aren't floating point values anyway, they're usually period delimited sequences of integers.

Comment: I added more details to the question addressing your questions mu too short. Thanks

Comment: Everything is working now when I simply wrote the route as   map.connect '/apiv3/:action/:id', :controller =>'apiv3', :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\.]+?/. If you would like to add an answer I will accept. Many thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get some looser requirements into the router system as in this one:

> [rails routing and params with a '.' in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276125/rails-routing-and-params-with-a-in-them)

The way to do that is to use [`:requirements`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7276495/479863) in one way or another.

[`map.resources`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources) doesn't understand the `:id` option or `:requirements` so these two won't work:

```
map.resources :api, :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\.]+?/, :format => /json|xml|plist|html/
map.resources :api, :requirements => { :resource => /.*/ }
```

`map.resources` does take a Hash of options though so you won't get an error when you pass it options that it doesn't understand.

The easiest thing to do is to define an extra route outside of `map.resources` that allows a dot in the `:id`. Something like this:

```
map.resources :api
map.connect '/apiv3/:action/:id', :controller =>'apiv3', :id => /.*/ # or whatever regex works for you
```

Or:

```
map.resources :api
map.connect '/apiv3/:action/:id', :controller =>'apiv3', :requirements => { :id => /.*/ }
```

You can put the `map.connect` before or after the `map.resources`.